# How should I prevent multiple inserts here?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am inserting 5000 transactions with about 6 banks, but I get 5000 bank rows in the database with duplicate names.

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }
}

public class Bank
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FinancialRecordContext : DbContext
{
    public FinancialRecordContext() : base("FinancialRecordDatabase") { }

    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }

    public Bank FindOrInsertBank(string bankName)
    {
        var bank = Banks.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Name == bankName);
        if (bank == null)
        {
            bank = new Bank { Name = bankName };
            Banks.Add(bank);
        }
        return bank;
    }
}
```

Then to insert I am looping through some data and inserting thusly:

```
        using (var context = new FinancialRecordContext())
        {
            foreach (var t in data)
            {
                var tran = new Transaction
                {
                    Description = t.Description,
                    Value = t.Value,
                    TransDate = t.TransDate,
                    Bank = context.FindOrInsertBank(t.BankName)
                };
                context.Transactions.Add(tran);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

It would appear that the `FindOrInsertBank` method is going to the database all the time and not looking locally at it's recently added, but not committed banks. How can/should I be doing this?

Should I `SaveChanges` after each bank insert? Not really what I want to do I want this to be all one transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions to try:

1) Check the `Local` collection of `DbSet<Bank>` first.

```
public Bank FindOrInsertBank(string bankName)
{
    var bank = Banks.Local.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Name == bankName);
    if (bank == null)
    {
        var bank = Banks.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Name == bankName);
        if (bank == null)
        {
            bank = new Bank { Name = bankName };
            Banks.Add(bank);
        }
    }
    return bank;
}
```

2) Force a call to `DetectChanges()` after each update

```
context.Transactions.Add(tran);
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

Comment: Ah, `Local`, much better than my change tracker query. I always forget this thing...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to query the change tracker (which is an in-memory query, not a database query):

```
using (var context = new FinancialRecordContext())
{
    foreach (var t in data)
    {
        Bank bank = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(e => e.Entity is Bank && e.State != EntityState.Deleted)
            .Select(e => e.Entity as Bank)
            .SingleOrDefault(b => b.Name == t.BankName);

        if (bank == null)
            bank = context.FindOrInsertBank(t.BankName);

        var tran = new Transaction
        {
            Description = t.Description,
            Value = t.Value,
            TransDate = t.TransDate,
            Bank = bank
        };
        context.Transactions.Add(tran);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edit**

Using the change tracker here *could be* bad for performance because `Bank.Name` is not the key of the entity and I guess the query would be a linear search through the entries. In this case using a handwritten dictionary might be the better solution:

```
using (var context = new FinancialRecordContext())
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Bank>();
    foreach (var t in data)
    {
        Bank bank;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(t.BankName, out bank))
        {
            bank = context.FindOrInsertBank(t.BankName);
            dict.Add(t.BankName, bank);
        }

        var tran = new Transaction
        {
            Description = t.Description,
            Value = t.Value,
            TransDate = t.TransDate,
            Bank = bank
        };
        context.Transactions.Add(tran);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, like the optimisation in the edit. Tried the change tracker and it didn't help, still had 5000 banks, maybe needed `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` also?

Comment: @weston: Hm, the change tracker query should be actually the verbose version of qujck's `Local` query. Can't see what might be wrong with the query. Anyway, forget it, using `Local` is cleaner obviously. `DetectChanges` is not needed because `DbSet.Add` will call it internally anyway. Either `Local` or the `dict` snippet are the way to go in my opinion.